# Consolidation of network scanning results into database

Tags: database, network-monitoring, asset-management

Need to scan local network time to time to monitor possible changes in MAC-IP-username combination.

Normally do it in several stages using nmap, pstools and other suitable tools, but am looking for one-shop solution to consolidate scanning results into database.

It would be good if the same software could track assets, both hardware and software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to some other questions, Look at [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com), it does inventory management by scanning the network and you can run some reports and setup alerts, it also posts changes that have occured.  It does handle software and hardware inventory.  I find it useful sine my network is spread over 28 sites